# Открытие зашифрованного файла

Tags: c#, winforms

Шифрую файл и сохраняю его

```
 private static void EncryptDES(string filePath, string text)
    {
        using (var shifr = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
        using (var cryptic = new DESCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            cryptic.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");
            cryptic.IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");
            using (var crshifr = new CryptoStream(shifr, cryptic.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
                crshifr.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
        }
    }
```

Потом пытаюсь расшифровать и открыть и вывести в richtextbox.

```
 private static string DecryptDES(string filePath)
    {
        using (var shifr = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read))
        using (var cryptic = new DESCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            cryptic.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");
            cryptic.IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");
            using (var crshifr = new CryptoStream(shifr, cryptic.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {

                using (var readStream = new StreamReader(crshifr))
                    return readStream.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
```

Выбивает ошибку: плохие данные

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47866/discussion-on-question-by-arakul---).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы сохранить всё содержимое `RichTextBox`, нужно использовать его свойство `Rtf`, которое содержит разметку.

Все disposable объекты нужно очищать после окончания работы с ними. Поэтому применяем оператор `using`.

Код записи:

```
var key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");
var IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");

using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
using (var cryptoProvider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider())
using (var encryptor = cryptoProvider.CreateEncryptor(key, IV))
using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fileStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream))
{
    streamWriter.Write(richTextBox1.Rtf);
}
```

Код чтения:

```
var key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");
var IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");

using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
using (var cryptoProvider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider())
using (var decryptor = cryptoProvider.CreateDecryptor(key, IV))
using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(fileStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(cryptoStream))
{
    richTextBox1.Rtf = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Функции шифрования и дешифрования, вот как должны были оформить их:

```
        private static void EncryptDES(string filePath, string text)
        {
            using (var shifr = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
            using (var cryptic = new DESCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                cryptic.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");
                cryptic.IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");
                using (var crshifr = new CryptoStream(shifr, cryptic.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
                    crshifr.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                }
            }
        }

        private static string DecryptDES(string filePath)
        {
            using (var shifr = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read))
            using (var cryptic = new DESCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                cryptic.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");
                cryptic.IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");
                using (var crshifr = new CryptoStream(shifr, cryptic.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (var readStream = new StreamReader(crshifr))
                        return readStream.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
```

Замените свой код ими, и проверьте. Если что-то не будет работать - напишите в вопрос уже полный пример.