# Хранение характеристик разных объектов

Tags: c#, unity3d

Допустим создал я класс `Characteristic`, что дальше делать?
Как мне для разных объектов загружать разные характеристики?

То есть допустим я добавляю каждому объекту данный класс в инспектор и грузить из файла по названию объекта?

Как это делаете вы?
И где лучше хранить информацию об объектах и как (ну там например броня, здоровье, припасы и т.д.).
Помогите разобраться.

Comment: вы бы уточнили, что вопрос про хранение в файлах и немного по-подробнее, а то без вашего комментария под уже удаленным ответом это ни разу не очевидно.

Comment: @rdorn, ну как бы некая база, я просто не знаю, в чем лучше хранить, да так, чтобы можно было усовершенствовать, без проблем или изменить у того или иного объекта определенную настройку прям из приложения. я смотрел в сторону xml или json, но их можно легко выдернуть и заменять...

Comment: _можно легко выдернуть и заменять_ - то есть вы хотите спрятать данные от пользователей? Отредактируйте вопрос, добавив в него всю необходимую информацию. / Можно просто дать файлам другое расширение (dat или bin вместо xml или json) - это уже отсечёт множество юзеров-хакеров. Можно сжимать эти файлы: использовать GZipStream/DeflateStream - добавляется буквально пара строк кода ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/563977/184217)). Можно их [шифровать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/585779/184217) - тогда вообще взломать будет сложно (но всё равно возможно).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, все сделал проще, ничего не нужно шифровать и мудрить. Сделал отдельно место для хранения xml'ок, и дело с концом, в самом приложении их нет, все будет лежать на сервере, при открытии все подгружаться будет и все, делов то..

Comment: _все будчет лежать на сервере_ - почему в вопросе ни слова о том, что приложение клиент-серверное?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov оно не клиент сервеное. У вас узкое понятие сервера видимо. Ну да ладно.

Comment: Поместите _всю_ необходимую информацию в вопрос. Откуда отвечающим знать, что у вас и как реализуется?

Comment: По-вашему пользователь не сможет изменить "загруженную xml'ку" во время рантайма?

Comment: Да и зачем вообще что-то защищать, если это чисто клиентское приложение? 99% пользователей будет все равно на взлом, а те люди из 1%, если это им действительно интересно, смогут сломать любую вашу защиту.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, каким образом они ее поменяют если она не будет соответствовать той, что лежит на сервере? Это невозможно.

Comment: Конечно невозможно, поменять данные в рантайме у какого-либо объекта в юнити - непосильная задача.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, если поменять в рантайме, то ничего не выйдет, так-как, данные не будут соответствовать с данными на сервере.

Comment: Да что вы говорите, будете каждый фрейм проверять файл на целостность через сервер?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, каждый фрейм, никто так не делает и даже не обязательно. Можно проверять раз в какое-то время, раз в минуту например. или когда происходят конкретные действия на те или иные моменты из файла. Что то выполнили проверили, что-то купили. проверили, сверили.

Comment: Ну т.е. приложение будет клиент-серверное с постоянной синхронизацией, о чем вам и написали выше, чего вы с человеком спорили - не ясно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас контент статический, то есть вы один раз его настроите в редакторе, а потом будете использовать в редакторе то смотрите в сторону `ScriptableObject`, основы [здесь можно глянуть](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1A3XRSS7XUo). Там создаете файл со структурой данных прямо в редакторе и настраиваете его там же, через редактор, а потом просто назначаете объект в проекте перетаскиванием как любого асета в качестве ссылки. Нет нужды писать код для его извлечения.

Как альтернатива можно хранить данные в отдельных файлах, самый простой способ для этого делаете сериализуемый объект. Далее сериализуете и сохраняете файл в папку внутри приложения. В обратном случае читаете файл из этой папки и десериализуете, получаете на выходе готовый объект с настройками.

Если же вам нужна полноценная база данных локально на одном устройстве, то можно посмотреть в сторону SqlLite, например можно [использовать этот плагин](https://github.com/robertohuertasm/SQLite4Unity3d).

Если же вам надо распределенно работать с данными, то уже смотрите в сторону полноценного сервера с базой данных.